# POI and setting cells to VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, alignment, vertical-alignment

Hey all I am trying to get my cell to vertical line instead of just being aligned by the left side using POI.

This is my java code:

```
static CellStyle headerCellStyle    = workbook.createCellStyle();

headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
Row headerRow   = null;        
sheet           = workbook.createSheet("String " + sheetname);

headerCellStyle.setWrapText(true);
headerCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
headerCellStyle.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
headerCellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);

// Create a Row
headerRow   = sheet.createRow(0);
```

However, the line *headerCellStyle.**setVerticalAlignment**(VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE);* has an error of:

> The method setVerticalAlignment(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.VerticalAlignment) in the type CellStyle is not applicable for the arguments (org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.VerticalAlignment)

How can i go about getting this to work if I have already defined it as an **static CellStyle headerCellStyle   = workbook.createCellStyle();**?

Changing to SS does not seem to have the **"middle"** option?

[image]

This is the difference within excel for those 2 types:

The default way:

[image]

The Middle way (the way I am wanting):

[image]

The Center way:

[image]

Comment: Look closely at your error - you've got a typo in the package name of your import! Needs to be `poi.ss.` not `poi.sl.`

Comment: @Gagravarr seems there is no option for middle with the SS?

Comment: Won't `CENTER` do what you need? (Different file formats call things different things)

Comment: Updated my OP to show the differences in each setting.

Comment: Your second image (the way I am wanting) shows [CellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setVerticalAlignment-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.VerticalAlignment-). Your third image shows [CellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setAlignment-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment-). There is a difference between `VerticalAlignment.CENTER` and `HorizontalAlignment.CENTER`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second image (the way you want) shows [CellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setVerticalAlignment-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.VerticalAlignment-). Your third image shows [CellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#setAlignment-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment-).

There is a difference between `setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER)` and `setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER)`. The first sets **vertical** alignment to center (aka middle). The second sets **horizontal** alignment to center.

Complete Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelVerticalAlignment {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

//  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
//       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

  try (Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xls") ) {

   CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   headerCellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   sheet.setColumnWidth(0, 20*256);
   Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
   row.setHeightInPoints(40);
   Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
   cell.setCellValue("1082192560 1868");

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: That indeed does bring it to the middle. Thanks!